# Why do aggregate functions return atleast 1 row

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

The query `select 1 from dual where false` returns 0 rows, but the query `select max(1) from dual where false` returns 1 row with NULL content.

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: if you add group by to the query its not return anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query with a `where 1=0` clause filters out all rows, and returns an empty set.

An aggregrate without a group by aggregates over the entire table.  If the table contains no row, the maximum will be `null`, but it still calculates the aggregate.